# Identification of Q-point in BJT

Tags: bjt

[image]

I am not able to understand why for the above problem \$ V_{ECQ} \$ = 6 V for the transistor Q-point to be in the center of the load line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The answer given here shows the value of VCEQ to be 6V, which is a positive quantity.*

And...

> *I am not able to understand why for the above problem \$V_{ECQ}\$ = 6 V*

I think you need to read that bit more carefully: -

[image]

They talk about \$V_{ECQ}\$ being +6 volts and that is correct because the emitter is taken as the reference point relative to the collector AND because the emitter is 6 volts more positive (there or thereabouts) than the collector, the voltage is positive and not negative.

**From comments:** -

> *I meant this in the comment: "The answer given here shows the value of
>   VECQ to be 6V, which is a positive quantity."*

@Soumee yes it should (nearly) but given that maybe 5% or 10% of the DC supply is lost across the emitter resistor, the better answer would account for that and make the collector quiescent voltage slightly closer towards the supply voltage.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typing error.

Comment: @Soumee what was?

Comment: So \$ V_{CEQ} \$ should be half of the voltage of the voltage rails for both pnp and npn transistors?

Comment: I meant this in the comment: "The answer given here shows the value of VECQ to be 6V, which is a positive quantity."

Comment: @Soumee yes it should (nearly) but given that maybe 5% or 10% of the DC supply is lost across the emitter resistor, the better answer would account for that and make the collector quiescent voltage slightly closer towards the supply voltage.

Answer (score 1):

The center of the load line will want to be at half the supply rail of -12V. So that center point would be -6V.

The output from the circuit is taken from the collector of the transistor and you want to select the center of the supply rails so as to permit the output to be able to support an symmetric swing around that point getting up close to the GND and -12V extremes without distortion or clamping.

Comment: The answer given here shows the value of \$ V_{CEQ} \$ to be 6V, which is a positive quantity. However, the supply has a voltage of -12V. So \$ V_{CEQ} \$ must be equal to -6V as you have already mentioned. Why have they taken a positive value for the quiescent voltage?

Comment: @Soumee - Probably some absolute value type of calculation. I did not spend time trying to follow that "solution sequence" and instead posted this answer to point out that the V<sub>CEQ</sub> would want to be the -6V value and explained why.